# A better approach instead of using String replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some operations for each element of an array of strings, when it matches a regexp.

I have been able to resolve this by using the replace function:

```
const anyRegExp = new RegExp('string[(\d)]');
const sampleArr = ['string[1].name','string[2].name' /*,...*/]
const myOp1 = (...args) => /* operations */
const myOp2 = (...args) => /* different operations */
sampleArr.forEach(key => key.replace(anyRegExp, (par1, par2, par3, par4) => {
  console.log(par1, par2, par3, par4);
  // prints: 'string[1]', '1', 1, 'string[1].name'
  //         'string[2]', '2', 2, 'string[2].name'
  if (par3 > 1) {
    myOp(par1,par2,par3,par4);
  } else {
    myOp2(par1,par2,par3,par4);
  }
}));
```

As you see, I am not really needing the replace operation at all. I know it does not modify my key anyway, I'd just love to know if there is any other kind of function defined in String more appropiate for this job.

I tried match, but it does not receive a function as second parameter.

**Output Sample (With google chrome)**

```
const temp1 = /Tests.MyTests\[(\d+)\]/
const temp2 = "Tests.MyTests[0].name"

temp2.match(temp1, (...args) => console.log('args',args))
 outputs--> ["Tests.MyTests[0]", "0"]

temp2.replace(temp1, (...args) => console.log('args',args))
 logs--> args ["Tests.MyTests[0]", "0", 0, "Tests.MyTests[0].name"]
 outputs--> "undefined.name"
```

As it can be seen, replace, receives a function, which gives me 4 parameters, which are the ones I want to use.

**match** does not log anything

```js
const temp1 = /Tests.MyTests\[(\d+)\]/
const temp2 = "Tests.MyTests[0].name"

temp2.match(temp1, (...args) => console.log('args',args));
```

```js
const temp1 = /Tests.MyTests\[(\d+)\]/
const temp2 = "Tests.MyTests[0].name"

temp2.replace(temp1, (...args) => console.log('args',args))
```

Comment: Wouldn't filtering your array work in this case?

Comment: Since you don't modify the key, what does your function *do* at all?

Comment: If I use filter, then I don't get access to the parameters provided by the replace function (I think). I will edit little bit the question hopefully for better understanding

Comment: You should escape the brackets when creating reqexps. E.g. const anyRegExp = /string\[(\d+)\]/

Comment: And yes, match does take function as second parameter. E.g. "foo (bar)".match(/foo/, (...args) => console.log(args))

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
for (let key of sampleArr)
    myOp(...key.match(anyRegExp)) // or anyRegExp.exec(key)
```

assuming that the regex always matches the whole string, not multiple times on parts of it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split` then `join` for example you want to replace any symbol characters regex with "-" then

`myString.split(/[^\w-]/).join('-')`